# in person Re-identification using adaBoost i am not able to select Yi

Tags: computer-vision

i am working on a project person Re-identification using adaBoost and i am confused to understand how will we select 'y' .
Let given training data (Xi,Yi) for N label.
where Xi=pair of images
      Yi={-1,1}
so how will we choose Yi ???

D. Gray and H. Tao. Viewpoint invariant pedestrian recognition
with an ensemble of localized features. In European
Conference on Computer Vision, 2008

Answer (score 1):

yi = -1 or yi = 1 means you have two labels in your data.

In the mentioned article you have one label for xi which have the two images of the same person and other label for xi which has two images of different persons.

So you can choose to label all the xi with two images of the same person to be 1 and for xi with two images of different persons as -1.